# Elasticsearch Bulk Data Insert Error Handling

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, error-handling, npm

I'm using elasticsearch for my data and I insert the data by using nodejs scripts. Sometimes there occur errors and the data doesn't inserted successfully to elasticsearch. I want to handle those errors. How can I handle the errors. Thanks for the helps.

Comment: Maybe you can show us a bit of the code you already have and what kind of errors you're getting. Help us help you!

Comment: You should update your question and not post new answers everytime you make an update :)